# Controls menu in InfoPath does not show all options

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, infopath

I had a SharePoint 2010 list form that I turned into an InfoPath form, however I see that the controls menu is limited. How do I get the full control menu to show instead of the limited?

**The limited "Controls" I get.**

[image: The limited "Controls" I see]

**The full control dropdown I need for my form.**

[image: The full control dropdown I need for my form.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. Been overloaded with work. I forgot when using a InfoPath for a list you will get limited controls and the full complement with a library form.